# Closing WiFi connections using the Managed API

Tags: c#, wifi

I'm writing a program using the [Managed WiFi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/). Here's how I get all the networks in range:

```
    void UpdateNetworks()
    {
        networks = new List<Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork>();
        WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        foreach(WlanClient.WlanInterface iface in client.Interfaces)
        {
            Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] nets = iface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
            foreach(Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork net in nets)
                networks.Add(net);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that after 18 calls to this method I can no longer connect:

> (0x80004005): An attempt was made to
>   establish a session to a network
>   server, but there are already too many
>   sessions established to that server.

Here's the constructor that's throwing the exception:

```
    public WlanClient()
    {
        Wlan.ThrowIfError(
            Wlan.WlanOpenHandle(Wlan.WLAN_CLIENT_VERSION_XP_SP2, IntPtr.Zero, out negotiatedVersion, out clientHandle));
        try
        {
            Wlan.WlanNotificationSource prevSrc;
            wlanNotificationCallback = new Wlan.WlanNotificationCallbackDelegate(OnWlanNotification);
            Wlan.ThrowIfError(
                Wlan.WlanRegisterNotification(clientHandle, Wlan.WlanNotificationSource.All, false, wlanNotificationCallback, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out prevSrc));
        }
        catch
        {
            Wlan.WlanCloseHandle(clientHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I believe this is because the client never closes the connections it opens. How do I close them explicitly? There's handle closing in the `catch` block, but it requires access to the client's private parts.

Comment: Are you making sure to call `WlanCloseHandle` even in non-exceptional cases? You don't show whether your class has a `Dispose` or not (or whether it's called correctly).

Comment: That's not my class, it's from the API, check the link for source.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, it does clean up in its `Dispose`. Are you making sure to call `Dispose` on your WlanClient instances, then? That's the most obvious first thing to check.

Comment: The compiler says that the client doesn't have a `Dispose()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're seeing problems only after a certain number of iterations, the problem is likely resource exhaustion of some sort, which sounds like resources aren't getting cleaned up in a timely manner.

From the comments above, it sounds like you're not disposing your `WlanClient` instances, which may be part (or all) of the problem. I can understand why you're not disposing them, though, because they don't give you any obvious way to do so. This seems like a really problematic design on their part. There are all kinds of design guidelines that say a class like this should give you either a public `Dispose` method or a public `Close` method, but even though they have *both* those methods, they deliberately made them both private.

But the class does implement `IDisposable`, so you can still clean it up by adding a `using` block:

```
using (var wlanClient = new WlanClient()) {
    ....
} // wlanClient will be disposed when flow leaves the block
```

This will make sure all of the object's resources get cleaned up at the moment flow leaves the `using` block (even if flow is leaving because there was an exception). Your connections will be closed, your unmanaged memory released, and whatever else needs to happen.

Comment: `'NativeWifi.WlanClient': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'`.

Comment: How do you tell that it does implement the `IDisposable`? It doesn't say `WlanClient : IDisposable` in the source.

Comment: Huh. The code I'm looking at (via the link in your question) does implement IDisposable. Perhaps they changed it since the version you downloaded? http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41381#78713 `public class WlanClient : IDisposable`

Comment: Yes, it would seem so, it was added in the latest change (which still was two years ago, I have no idea how I had an earlier version). Thanks.

Comment: @ HUI : would you please share the part of the code where your calling the Connect (4 parameters ) method ... I am getting an error namely incorrect parameters ... Please help .. have been breaking my head for 4 dyas

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem.
I tried Mr Joe White solution but I received an error that wlanClient cannot be converted to System.IDisposable.
Since this problem is related to disposal of WlanClient instances, I only defined 1 instance as class member and used it so many times in method [void UpdateNetworks()]. I did not receive  any error.
Remove line

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
```

from your method and define it in your class. like the following:

```
public partial class frm_main : Form
{
     private WlanClient client = new WlanClient();

     private void UpdateNetworks()
     {
         var networks = new List<Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork>();
         foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface iface in client.Interfaces)
         {
             Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] nets = iface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
             foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork net in nets)
                 networks.Add(net);
         }
         MessageBox.Show(networks.Count.ToString());
     }
}
```

Reference: [Managed WiFi error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792046/managed-wifi-error)