# Managed WiFi error

Tags: c#, wifi, managed

I have been using this API ( http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/ )successfully and without any major problems. Until today at least...

I have implemented a program in C# which among others retrieves the BSSID of the connected A.P. and the number of the available wireless networks in proximity and does a number of checks. When I am connected to a certain A.P. I get a message and when I am not connected to this specific A.P. (but to another one or I am not connected at all) I get another message. Simple as that.

I did this, connection to the A.P,  check once and only - when the application starts.

But...I wanted to add a timer so that this check happens every 30 or 60 seconds (and not only at the beginning). The problem is that it runs for a few times (maximum 10) and then the program freezes and I get the following message:

*Win32Exception was unhandled:
An attempt was made to establish a session to a network server, but there are already too many sessions established to that server*

and the message box points to WlanClient client = new WlanClient();

I don't know what is incorrect and although the code compiles correctly I get this error.

Maybe is something with the dispose of the objects?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Maybe is something with the dispose of the objects?"

You are right, that is whats probably missing from your code.

Make 
`WlanClient client = new WlanClient();` 
a class variable and use it as often as you like.

```
... class Yourclass
{
     private static WlanClient client = new WlanClient(); 
...
```

Comment: this does hoewever not solve the problem when you want to repeatedly check for the wifi ssids surrounding you etc. as the client will stop updating. How to dispose the client properly so that a repeated search can be done?

Comment: Found the solution for a repeated scan here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933478/3801213